# My custom user metadata is only active for only admin but i want it to be active on all users especially customers

Tags: users, user-meta

How can i make custom user metadata which is only active for only admin be active on all users especially customers. Attached are snapshots of the issue.
[image: Admin profile-first 4 metadata showing]

[image: Customer profile-the first 4 metadata is not displaying there.]

Comment: Do other users even _have_ values for that metadata?

Comment: yes, i uploaded a csv file which is suppose to update the various fields of the other users

Comment: Did it work? Have you checked if the meta is actually in the database for those users?

Comment: the meta for the admin shows but the rest is not displaying. So that is making me think that the key is working in only the admin role and not working for the remaining roles, especially customers.